# Spatial Data not returning correct distance

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sqlgeography

I have the two following locations.

They're both towns in Australia , State of Victoria

```
Fitzroy,-37.798701, 144.978687
Footscray,-37.799736, 144.899734
```

I've followed this tutorial [to work out the distance between two cities](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/Jun/21/Basic-Spatial-Data-with-SQL-Server-and-Entity-Framework-50)

After running `geography::Point(Latitude, Longitude , 4326)` on the latitude and longitude provided for each location, my Geography column for each row is populated with the following:

```
Fitzroy, 0xE6100000010C292499D53BE642C0A7406667511F6240
Footscray, 0xE6100000010C89B7CEBF5DE642C02D23F59ECA1C6240
```

In my SQL Query, I have the following which works out the distance between both towns. Geo being my Geography column

```
DECLARE @s geography
DECLARE @t geography

SET @s = (select Geo from Location.Cities where StateId = 7 and Id = 6918) -- Fitzroy
SET @t = (select Geo from Location.Cities where StateId = 7 and Id = 6923) -- Footscray

SELECT @s.STDistance(@t)
```

The result I get is

```
6954.44911927616
```

I then looked at formatting this as in Australia we go by KM so after some searching I found two solutions one for Miles and the other KM

So I changed Select statement to look like this

```
select @s.STDistance(@t)/1000  -- format to KM
```

My result is then

```
6.95444911927616
```

When I go to google maps and do a direction request between the locations provided above it says 10.2km (depending on traffic)

Now I'm new to this spatial data within SQL, why would I get a different results?

Comment: Directions is based on distance by road which is not the shortest distance between the points, what you are getting is direct point to point distance from sql.

Comment: This is probably distance as the crow flies. Roads are not straight (unless the Romans got further afield than we thought).

Comment: @ughai I see, is there a way I can format the distance i.e round it up or down so I can get rid of trailing numbers after the point ?

Comment: Also when I put the two points into Google Maps, this returns the shortest route as *8.2km*, not 10.2km. So a shortening of 1.3km due to deviations in roads would be quite acceptable.

Comment: Sure, you can use `FLOOR`,`CEILING`, or `CONVERT(DECIMAL(9,0),x)` based on your requirement

Comment: There's also ROUND(), which you pass the SF to in the second argument. But you'll need to trim the truncated decimal places.

Comment: I want to return a integer value and then compare this to a parameter passed in so If I pass in 50 then I would want to return all locations whereby the distance is less then 50

Comment: @JohnnyBell can you show me an example as I can't find an example online probably googling incorrectly.

Comment: Well the SQL engine should be able to implicitly compare integer and float values. So you shouldn't need to convert them to full integers, unless of course you want them rounded off for a specific reason. If you want accuracy, just keep the decimal values.

Comment: @JohnnyBell Let me explain the situation a bit more because I'm getting confused. the user on the front end types in a city and selects a radius of 50 km I then call the db select the GEO field that matches the city passed in and I then need to add the 50KM radius to the chosen GEO and filter the results to make sure whats returned falls in to the radius of 50km this is where I'm getting confused

Comment: Are you looking for STBuffer? This would allow you to add a buffer around a geopoint and query for any data within that buffer